# How to update UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell after transition to landscape

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have the following collectionView:
https://youtu.be/dY2MDeFINEY

I want the images to stay centered during transitions in landscape and even the "paging-behaviour" of the collectionView should remain.
To achieve this, I have tried a couple of things. My current code (just for the transition) looks like this:
**Code of the TableViewController, which holds the TableViewCell with the collectionView:**

```
...
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)//The position of the row doesn't change
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? PlantDetailImageTableViewCell
        tableView.reloadData()
        cell?.respondToTransition()
    }
...
```

**The method respondToTransition (inside the TableViewCell which holds the collectionView) looks like this:**

```
func respondToTransition() {
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: pageControl.currentPage, section: 0)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.pageControl.currentPage = indexPath.row
            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

**My flow layout is the following:**

```
extension PlantDetailImageTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return collectionView.frame.size
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.collectionView.frame.size.width)
    }
}
```

The result on transition to landsape is the following:
https://youtu.be/RlTX0LgfKEY

How could I force the images to keep centered. In addition it seems like the collectionView "losts" a "bit" of their "paging behaviour".
The view debugger of Xcode shows the following for landscape (the marked blue is the imageview inside the collectionView cell):
[image: Xcode view debugger]

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:**
The problem only occurs, when I'm trying to go from portrait to landscape. So if I start the app in landscape, then everything works as expected.

Comment: maybe it is just about the cell's imageView's `Content Mode`? What is your configuration about this?

Comment: @emrcftci No it is set to .aspectFit. The problem only occurs, when I'm trying to go from portrait to landscape. So if I start with landscape, then everything works as expected...

Comment: @finebel you need to invalidate the layout instead of reloadData inside the viewWilTransition method

Comment: @LeoDabus  which layout do you mean (which method should I call instead of tableView.reloadData() )?

Comment: `collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`

Comment: I can't do this on this position, because the TableViewController doesn't hold the collectionView itself. Instead I call ```respondToTransition()``` on my custom TableViewCell. In this method I'm going to call ```collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()```. (See the second code block in my question)

Comment: You don't need to reload your data when the device rotates (table and collection view). I am not sure why you are calling that method on the cell. try to just call  `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()`,. You might need to customize the collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAt based on the collectionView frame.

Comment: I will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution for the problem.
As LeoDabus mentioned in the comment section, the call for `tableView.reloadData()` in the TableViewController was unnecessary. So I deleted this one and in addition, I have changed `respondToTransition()` to the following:

```
func respondToTransition() {
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: pageControl.currentPage, section: 0)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()//!!!
        self.pageControl.currentPage = indexPath.row
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}
```

My flow layout is still the same...